# git merge from one fork to another

Tags: git, git-merge

I forked a origin git repository (repo1) which has many modules (let's say A, B, C) and made some changes to one of the module (let's assume in A) in my fork (myname/repo1). By the time, I plan to pull my changes from fork to the origin repo(repo1), origin repo is been refactored and each module is a git repo (repoA, repoB, repoC) now. I forked the repoA now and want to first merge from previous fork (myname/repo1 - moduleA) to this one (myname/repoA). How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of ways to handle this. You can't merge since the commit IDs and file locations have changed. Probably the simplest is to rebase your changes onto the new repository, then merge. Since the filenames have moved, you'll have to apply the same changes as well.

First step is to bring in the new repository as a remote. `git remote add repoA url-to-repo-a` and `git fetch repoA`.

Then you need to apply the same filename changes as were done to create repoA to your branch. This can be done with [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) using the `--subdirectory-filter`. After checking out your branch, run something like `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter moduleA/ master..HEAD`. This will make the contents of the directory `moduleA/` into the new root. `master..HEAD` will restrict that change to just your branch. For safety, you can tag your current branch before running the filter so you have an easier time recovering in case the filter goes wrong.

You should be able to now merge normally.